# Why doesn't this codewars algorithm work using only functions?

Tags: python, algorithm

I have already tried using a visualizer but this problem only returns none. This is the codewars question: https://www.codewars.com/kata/calculating-with-functions/solutions/python

```
def zero(f = None): return 0 if not f else f(0)
def one(f = None): return 1 if not f else f(1)
def two(f = None): return 2 if not f else f(2)
def three(f = None): return 3 if not f else f(3)
def four(f = None): return 4 if not f else f(4)
def five(f = None): return 5 if not f else f(5)
def six(f = None): return 6 if not f else f(6)
def seven(f = None): return 7 if not f else f(7)
def eight(f = None): return 8 if not f else f(8)
def nine(f = None): return 9 if not f else f(9)

def plus(y): return lambda x: x+y
def minus(y): return lambda x: x-y
def times(y): return lambda  x: x*y
def divided_by(y): return lambda  x: x/y
four(plus(nine))
```

Comment: You're not calling `nine`.  Try `four(plus(nine()))`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to call `nine()`; otherwise `nine` is just a function object and can't be mixed with integers for numeric operations.

```
print(four(plus(nine())))
```

This outputs:

```
13
```